# Datepicker date is out by 1 day

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Ever since the clocks went forwards and we changed to BST, my datepicker is always returning the day before whatever is selected.

Any ideas as to why?

Here is my code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.trans_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
    altField : '#transaction_date',
    altFormat : '@',
    firstDay: 1,
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Converting the timestamp that the datepicker is providing shows the previous day at 23:00hrs

The code I am writing could be run in any timezone, I need to ensure the correct day is being returned.

Comment: Please, explain BST.

Comment: @Václav British Summer Time

Answer (score 0):

**'@'** is unix timestamp if you convert this timestamp you will get the exact date you have selected from datepicker.

```
$(function () {
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['en']);
        $('.trans_date').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            altField: '#transaction_date',
            altFormat: '@',
            firstDay: 1,
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            onSelect:function(){
                alert(new Date(parseInt($("#transaction_date").val(), 10)));
            }
        });

    });
```

I have created a fiddle and can check that : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/93dxd0wy/)

Most probably you are pasting the timeStamp in browser console window that why you getting such time, try once in IE or Chrome.

Comment: Seems that the issue is with my WordPress instance... Although I have the timezone set to London (BST) it's reading the timestamp wrongly (giving me -1 hour which converts to previous date at 11pm). I change the WordPress setting to UTC +1 and it returns the correct time!